# Why doesn't my iPhone 11 connect to my external monitor via HDMI?

Tags: iphone, ios, display, hdmi

I want to connect my iPhone 11 (iOS 17) to my external monitor via HDMI.

I use a [Sharllen RJ45 Ethernet Adapter 4 in 1 Lightning to HDMI Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B091923NWM) ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6qfz.png)), as well as a standard HDMI cable, which is plugged to the external monitor.  That works well with my iPhone 12 Mini with iOS 15.7 and my iPad 9 with IpadOS 15.6.1. However it does not work with my iPhone 11 (iOS 17).

I Googled the issue and I found on [Reddit](https://redd.it/15x8080) that the issue may be:

> iOS 17 requires that your cables be Apple certified (meaning they licensed the lightning mechanism).

Why doesn't my iPhone 11 connect to my external monitor via HDMI?

Comment: The Amazon listing claims iPhone 11 compatibility, some reviews mention HDMI issues though. It might help to try a different adapter to see whether it makes a difference.

Comment: Also, the certiifcate/MFi topic might very well be a red herring, the problem could also be related to something else. You might get better answers (and comments) if you focus the question on the problem (and not on some rumors).

Comment: @nohillside thanks for the feedback. "The Amazon listing claims iPhone 11 compatibility" the listing was written before iOS 17 was released. Agreed, it'd be interesting to try another adapter but I don't have another one with lightening. I added the links to show my research as my questions that don't show research tend to attract more downvotes and closes votes (not specific to this site, but the entire SE network), but I agree that the first paragraph suffices.

Comment: I wouldn't call it research, actually, and as you can see from the comments and close votes, it distracts from the issue at hand because the question reads if you seek confirmation of the "certificate required" issue (which also triggers the close votes).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From what I have gathered so far, the issue stems from iOS 17. That's based on:

1. Several comments that I have read on Reddit, while I have only read one comment claiming the contrary.
2. My own experience with an iPhone 12 Mini with iOS 15.7, an iPad 9 with IpadOS 15.6.1, an iPhone 11 running iOS 16, an iPhone 11 running iOS 17 and an iPhone 12 Pro Max running iOS 16.7.2 using the same cable ([Sharllen RJ45 Ethernet Adapter 4 in 1 Lightning to HDMI Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B091923NWM) ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6qfz.png)) + standard HDMI cable, which is plugged to the external monitor). Only the iPhone with iOS 17 didn't work.